# Get text/value from textbox after value/text changed server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a `FormView` with data(`DataSource`,`DataBind`) that I fill with  `value='<%# Eval("Name") %>'` , but after I'm changing the text in `TextBox` and press update button I see the same value that before, I cant see new value that I have typed.

What I am missing here?

my html

```
<asp:FormView ID="MainFormTemplate" runat="server">  
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="li_result" runat="server">
            <div class="col-3">
                <input id="txt_Name"   runat="server"   value='<%# Eval("Name") %>'>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:Button id="btn_Update" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Update_Click" Text="Update" />
```

Server side

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (DB_MikaDataContext data = new DB_MikaDataContext())
    { 
        MainFormTemplate.DataSource = data.File_Projects.Where(x => x.Num_Tik.Equals("12")).ToList();
        MainFormTemplate.DataBind();             
    }        
}


public void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    //using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
    HtmlInputText twt = (HtmlInputText)MainFormTemplate.FindControl("txt_Name");
    string text = twt.Value;//i see old value ,not new one that i typed in text box    
}
```

Comment: @Vova..when you click the submit button, form is posted and the new value typed in text box is lost, the value that is coming from the server will be only reflected

Comment: are you using JavaScript/jQuery in your site??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In every `postback`, you are always getting the old value from your database. The solution is check if the page is being rendered for the first time (**`!IsPostBack`**) then set your `MainFormTemplate`'s `DataSource` else if is being loaded in response to a postback (**`IsPostBack`**) get the `txt_Name`'s value like this:

```
HtmlInputText twt;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (!IsPostBack)
      {
           using (DB_MikaDataContext data = new DB_MikaDataContext())
           { 
                MainFormTemplate.DataSource = data.File_Projects.Where(x => x.Num_Tik.Equals("12")).ToList();
                MainFormTemplate.DataBind();
           }
      }
      else 
      {
           twt = MainFormTemplate.FindControl("txt_Name") as HtmlInputText;
      }           
}

protected void btn_Update_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string text = twt.Value; // You will get the new value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with `Page_Load` executing every `postback`, you are always writing value from database (?), and value sent from browser is lost (although still exist in `Page.Request.Form` member).

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET, When a page is submitted, the `Page_Load` event runs before the button click event. So, the `textbox` value gets repopulated with its original value before the click event looks at that value.

If this is the situation, then you can wrap the code that assigns the value to the `textbox` in an if block like this:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    HtmlInputText twt = (HtmlInputText)MainFormTemplate.FindControl("txt_Name");
    string text = twt.Value;
}
```

Hope this helps you.