# How to get TextBox value on page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have developed a web application using ASP.NET and C#.NET. My client wants the page to hold the data even if the page refreshes. So, I am trying to read the `Textbox` value and putting into the session but in page load event I find the `TextBox` as empty.
Here is what I am trying:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["name"] = txtName.Text.Trim();
}
```

I have also tried with this:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    Session["name"] = txtName.Text.Trim();
}
```

But still the same.

Comment: Your problem is `postback`. Check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/34545012/2946329

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to implement something like this, you would probably want to set the Session variable only when a `PostBack` occurred and if it was an initial load of a page, check if the Session value existed and use it instead.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    { 
         // This page is initially being loaded, check the Session
         // and use it
         txtName.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["name"]);
    }
    else
    {
         // It's not a Postback, so store the value for later use
         Session["name"] = txtName.Text.Trim();
    } 

    // Your other code here
}
```

You may also want to make sure that you actually have an event that triggers a `PostBack` to ensure that the Session variable actually gets set. This event could even be a `TextChanged` event on the `txtName` control (just make sure the `AutoPostBack` property is set to `true` :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtName_TextChanged">
```

Comment: for first solution I have tried and getting null after page refreshes but for the second solution the page will be reload every time which may make the page slower as I have more controls.

Comment: Your first solution will always set the Session value to an empty string (or the default value for your `txtName` control) and your second approach will essentially do the same thing (except only triggering on the initial load). 

You need to discern between requests (`PostBack` or not) and handle accordingly (i.e. setting the Session during postbacks and reading from it otherwise).

The above solution should do what you need. The page is going to be reloaded each time any type of event occurs unless you are explicitly using some type of asynchronous post (e.g. AJAX, PartialPostBacks, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (IsPostBack) {
    if(Session["name"] == null)
      Session["name"] = txtName.Text.Trim();
  else
   txtName.Text = Session["name"].ToString() 
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but still I am getting null after the page refreshes.

Comment: are you using async postback ?

Comment: This seems to be setting the Session value if a PostBack did not occur (`!IsPostBack)`, so it will always store the empty value in the Session when the page is first loaded and subsequently it will always be empty.

Comment: actually my client wants the page to behave in this way so that sometime they auto log off in between filling in a form (after inactivity for some reason). So, they wants a way out of it to get the page pre loaded with all those information they filled in before logging off.

Comment: If you want to handle that type of behavior barsan, then you will want to add a Session Timeout to ensure that the values will not be read from the Session after a certain period of time. Although depending on the amount of users in your application, it's likely that the App Pool might recycle in that time, thus wiping out the Session for you.

Comment: Session would not work with auto-log off is because during log off or session timeout, the session object would be destroyed and all the information stored in it. You need to save such information on client side, not server side.