# Listbox SelectedIndex always returns -1

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem, when I try to get selectedindex from asp:listbox in codebehind, it always stays -1, even thought on the page it is selected. I am fully updating this list every minute. For loading listItems, the entire list gets erased and written back again.

Code samples:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" 
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
   AutoPostBack="false">                
</asp:ListBox>
```

In codebehind:

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   itemsIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(); //It is always -1
   itemToBeRescheduled = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

Tried using if(!isPostBack).. but the index stayed -1 and it only erased my items from the list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AutoPostBack="false"?

Comment: Regardless of having it true or false, selected index is -1, but if it is set to be true, items on in list are not allowed to be selected.

Comment: You should have AutoPostBack enabled and get the selected index before removing all items. You have to check if the way you are updating the list every minute is causing the selected index to be lost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get text/value from textbox after value/text changed server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544500/get-text-value-from-textbox-after-value-text-changed-server-side)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, it happens when you rebind ListView on postback again. In order to prevent it, we normally place binding inside **!IsPostback**.

*For example,*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ListBox1.DataSource = new List<ListItem>()
        {
            new ListItem("One", "1"),
            new ListItem("Two", "2"),
            new ListItem("Three", "3")
        };
        ListBox1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: This Postback works nice, but only once on pageload, how do i update list with dynamically appearing and dissapearing listItems?

Answer (score 0):

When I have:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="140px" Width="290px" Font-Size="22px" autopostback="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And:

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
        TextBox1.Text = "-1";
    else
        TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

I don't get ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1.