# how to retain dynamic created button after post back in asp web forms

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i have given task that i have to create three tabs ,morning & day & evening inside morning tab i have to display button from 10:00 am to 12 :pm similarly for day and evening i have to make  three tabs on page load with click of there button .i have done but getting error like all button disappear on click of any button.. please answer me how to do it and also how to select/deselect clicked button with color  .

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
           // Response.Write(((Button)pnlButtons.FindControl("10-0")).);
        }
    }

 protected void Tab3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
        for (int i = 4; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 60; j += 15)
            {


                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Text = i + "-" + j;
                btn.ID = i + "-" + j;
                //btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(btntime_Click);

                btn.Click += btn_Click;
                pnlButtons.Controls.Add(btn);
                Label1.Text = "your sheduled time between 4 PM to 6 PM";
            }
       }
```

at aspx page

Comment: Have a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544500/get-text-value-from-textbox-after-value-text-changed-server-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic controls are not maintained on postback, so you would have to recreate them on every postback (e.g. in `Page_Load` ). An alternative would be to put the buttons in a Panel in the markup. That panel would have the `Visible` property set to `false` initially. In `Tab3_Click`, you could set `Visible="true"`.