# How to register events with dynamically added user controls?

Tags: asp.net

I have the following **user control** (**`CustomerControl.ascx`**):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CustomerControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="CustomerControl" %>

<tr>
    <td><%= this.FirstName %></td>
    <td><%= this.LastName %></td>
    <td><%= this.Email %></td>
    <td><%= this.Service %></td>
    <td><%= this.Amount %></td>
    <td>
        <button ID="DelCustomerBtn" OnServerClick="OnDelBtnClicked" runat="server">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It's a table row with a Delete button that mirrors the `Customers` table (`Id`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email`, `Service`, `Amount`). The **code-behind** file is (**`CustomerControl.ascx.cs`**):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add data-id = id_of_current_row_in_database
    DelCustomerBtn.Attributes.Add("data-id", this.Id.ToString());
}

private int id;

private string firstName;

private string lastName;

private string email;

private string service;

private decimal amount;

public event EventHandler DelBtnClicked;

protected void OnDelBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DelBtnClicked != null)
        DelBtnClicked(this, e);
}

public int Id
{
    get { return id; }
    set { id = value; }
}

public string FirstName
{
    get { return firstName; }
    set { firstName = value; }
}

public string LastName
{
    get { return lastName; }
    set { lastName = value; }
}

public string Email
{
    get { return email; }
    set { email = value; }
}

public string Service
{
    get { return service; }
    set { service = value; }
}

public decimal Amount
{
    get { return amount; }
    set { amount = value; }
}
```

The **starting page** (**`Default.aspx`**) has the following in it:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First</th>
            <th>Last</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Service</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="RowPlaceholder" runat="server" />
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Finally, its **code-behind** file (**`Default.aspx.cs`**) has:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Retrieve records from the DB:
        CustomersDataContext dataContext = new CustomersDataContext();
        var users = from user in dataContext.Customers
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = user.Id,
                        FirstName = user.FirstName,
                        LastName = user.LastName,
                        Email = user.Email,
                        Service = user.Service,
                        Amount = user.Amount
                    };

        // Declare CustomerControl object to hold controls:
        CustomerControl CustomerControl;

        // Add CustomerControl controls for each record in the DB:
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            // Load the CustomerControlcontrol:
            CustomerControl = (CustomerControl)LoadControl("~/CustomerControl.ascx");

            // Set the control's data:
            CustomerControl.Id = user.Id;
            CustomerControl.FirstName = user.FirstName;
            CustomerControl.LastName = user.LastName;
            CustomerControl.Email = user.Email;
            CustomerControl.Service = user.Service;
            CustomerControl.Amount = user.Amount;
            CustomerControl.DelBtnClicked += HandleDelBtnClicked;

            // Add the control to RowPlaceholder:
            RowPlaceholder.Controls.Add(CustomerControl);
        }
    } // endif
}

public void HandleDelBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    // Retrieve id_of_current_row_in_database, as set in user control
    int id = int.Parse(btn.Attributes["data-id"].ToString());

    CustomersDataContext dataContext = new CustomersDataContext();
    var find = from cst in dataContext.Customers
               where cst.Id == id
               select cst;

    dataContext.Customers.DeleteOnSubmit(find.First());
    dataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

## Idea behind this

Store the id of each record in the database in `data-id` attribute of the `button` with id of `DelCustomerBtn`. Retrieve the value of `data-id` in order to find the record by id (suing Linq to SQL) and delete it.

## Problem

This code despite being super simplistic, does not work. When I click on Delete button, the page refreshes, and I no longer see any rows in the `<table>`. No data ever gets deleted from the database.

## What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Controls that are added dynamically in code-behind must be recreated on every postback (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341477/how-to-retain-dynamic-created-button-after-post-back-in-asp-web-forms/37347838#37347838).

Comment: @ConnorsFan If I remove the `if (!IsPostBack)` condition, then I get: `Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.`

Comment: Did you consider using a ListView or a Repeater, instead of creating the controls "by hand"? You could insert your user control in an ItemTemplate, or just specify the content of the ItemTemplate, without defining a user control.

Comment: @ConnorsFan In this particular project, I need to use user controls. I tried asp.net `Table` with my user control having a `TableRow`, however that did not work. The error was that a table did not have a definition for `cutomercontroler_ascx`, something like that; a user control cannot be added to a `Table`

Comment: I wish someone could point out why my code doesn't do anything to the db!