# Form get blank when Page_Load function is called?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing a problem in my form. There are two text field and then there is drop-down menu, which link to a database.

When I click on the drop down menu, my two text fields are getting empty.

```
protected void OnChange_Acdemics(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList list = (DropDownList)Sender;
        string value = (string)list.SelectedValue;

        // degrees_dropdown.Visible = true;
        try
        {

            //   String query = "SELECT Degree_types.detail,Degree_Detail.GPA FROM Degree_Detail INNER JOIN Degree_types ON Degree_Detail.Degree_tilte = Degree_types.Degree_title where Degree_types.degree_type = '" + value + "';";
            String query = "Select detail from Degree_Detail where id=" + int.Parse(value) + ";";
            Dt = dbComm.GetDataTable(query);
            Degree_Selection.DataTextField = "detail";
            // Degree_Selection.DataValueField = "GPA";
            Degree_Selection.DataSource = Dt;
            Degree_Selection.DataBind();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably you have the `postback` problem. Check here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544500/get-text-value-from-textbox-after-value-text-changed-server-side

Comment: So you mean on every onClick we first get the value and then again save them..

Comment: Can you show a sample code how you are linking the drop-down with the database and text fields?

Comment: Can u Please Eleborate your answer i cant get what u say?

Comment: sure  Ashraf Abusada .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take care of this by using `Page.IsPostBack`:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   // load page 
}
else
{
   // check input values and set it again
}
```

Comment: You can use Ajax control toolkit for partial loading of any control that causes postbacks.