# Telerik Grid not showing data after postback in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am trying to create a Telerik RadGrid control with some basic data, and am using the Simple Data Bind method provided [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-binding/understanding-data-binding/server-side-binding/simple-data-binding).

```
<div id="divRadGrid">
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnSortCommand="RadGrid1_SortCommand" AllowSorting="True"></telerik:RadGrid>
</div>
```

Here's the code behind. When the user clicks the Run button, everything works fine. However, if I click on any event inside the grid, such as Sorting on a column, I see the page refreshes, but the grid does not display anything.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Telerik.Web.UI;

namespace TelerikDemoWebAppBlank2
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public DataTable SalespersonProductionDT { get; set; }
        public DataTable NewBusinessDT { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void BtnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getData();
            processNewBusiness();
        }

        protected void RadGrid1_SortCommand(object sender, GridSortCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            dataBindGrid(RadGrid1, NewBusinessDT);
        }

        private void getData()
        {
            SalespersonProductionDT = new DataTable();
            Sprocs._pDash_SalespersonProduction(BeginDate.SelectedDate.Value, EndDate.SelectedDate.Value, SalespersonProductionDT);

            NewBusinessDT = new DataTable();
            Sprocs._pDash_NewBusiness(BeginDate.SelectedDate.Value, EndDate.SelectedDate.Value, NewBusinessDT);
        }

        private void processNewBusiness()
        {
            dataBindChart(RadHtmlChart3, NewBusinessDT);
            dataBindGrid(RadGrid1, NewBusinessDT);
        }

        private void dataBindChart(RadHtmlChart radHtmlChart, DataTable dt)
        {
            radHtmlChart.DataSource = dt;
            radHtmlChart.DataBind();
        }

        private void dataBindGrid(RadGrid radGrid, DataTable dt)
        {
            radGrid.DataSource = dt;
            radGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try doing your IsPostBack check and binding in the page load method or change the DataTable to be Static

Comment: Probably your problem is `postback`. Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544500/get-text-value-from-textbox-after-value-text-changed-server-side

Comment: @MethodMan, how would changing my DataTable to be Static help?

Comment: you must not be familiar with Postbacks and how the data once sent to the server is not retained on the page during the load but setting up proper postback checks as well as rebinding, you will see what I am talking about..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use RadGrid, you want to take the advantage of ***[NeedDataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-binding/understanding-data-binding/server-side-binding/advanced-data-binding-(using-needdatasource-event))*** event.

The main reason is it knows when to bind data. You don't even need ***RadGrid1_SortCommand*** in your code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
       radGrid.Visible = false;
   }
}

protected void BtnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radGrid.Visible = true;
    radGrid.Rebind();
}

// Make sure you attach RadGrid_NeedDataSource event to grid inside markup.
protected void RadGrid_NeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
   var dt = new DataTable();
   Sprocs._pDash_NewBusiness(BeginDate.SelectedDate.Value, 
      EndDate.SelectedDate.Value, dt);

   radGrid.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't seem to work because on the first page load, the user did not yet specify BeginDate and EndDate and then clicked Run button. So those values are NULL.

Comment: You can hide radGrid on PageLoad; it won't call NeedDataSource until you click on BtnRun button. I updated the answer.