# dynamically created listbox c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have to create  multiple `listbox`  and bind them as they created  dynamically. I have created `listbox` as loop is for creating no of `listbox` as needed

```
for(int i=0;i<requirement;i++)
{
  Listbox dynamiclistbox = new listbox();
  //then i bind it with a list<> 
  //then i add listbox to a panel
  panel.Controls.Add(dynamiclistbox);
}
```

My problem is that when i click on submit button the dynamic controls disappear as dynamic controls loose state on `postback`
can someone help me  to create no. of  `listbox` dynamically and bind also  bind them on same button click . and get the `listbox` on `postback`

i.e, to know the selected item on `listbox`

Comment: The postback issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544500/get-text-value-from-textbox-after-value-text-changed-server-side

Comment: You have to (re)create the ListBoxes on every PostBack. You will have to store `requirement` somewhere and when there is a PostBack, do the `for-loop` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to put your code inside `Page_Load` event. If it is already there, then you probably have it inside something like

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
    //Your code
}
```

If that is the case, then you will need to put your code outside the `if`, since it is only adding the controls when it is not a postback and you need to add them when it is postback as well.

EDIT:

Currently the controls are created on button click. It is advisable to have a separate function which receives an input and generates the controls, add them to `panel`. Call this function from your click event. When this is correct, create an `asp:HiddenField` and set its `Value` to the input you need in the click handler. On `Page_Load` call your function with the `Value` of your `HiddenField`.

Comment: Thanks Lajos for reply but listbox will be created on button click i have created number of listbox successfully and they also binded to list. But the problem is i want the selected text on listbox(dynamically created listbox) but on postback listbox disappear .

Comment: Thanks for answer Your answer make me clear on the concept of dynamic controls. my mistake was just that i was also creating dynamic list again at (ispostback) and in ispostback i was finding control listbox . inspite of finding it is my savebutton event .

Answer (score 0):

write code for binding in `!IsPostBack` section

```
for(int i=0;i<requirement;i++)
{
  Listbox dynamiclistbox = new listbox();
          dynamiclistbox.CssClass = "";
          dynamiclistbox.ID = ""
          dynamiclistbox.EnableViewState = true;

  if (!IsPostBack){}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i need to create dynamic listbox on a button click so i cant create it at !ispostback but now i get my answer above . but also thanks for your answer