# Read and wirte Data without use forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-input

I hope you can help me. I got a problem with reading and writing in and out from inputs in HTML.

Code:

`<html>
    <input id="test" value="" type="text"/>
</html>`

in c# I access the value with:

`test.value="test";`

It works without any problems.

If i fill the Input on Page_load. I cant read the new value which was be entered by user.
I dont want to reload the Page.

Edit:

It dont solve my problem but it works too.

on Page_load

`test.Attributes.Add("placeholder",value)`

and on callback i read the new value with

`test.value`

Comment: Check for `IsPostBack` like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34545012/2946329

Comment: this dont work for me i can access the value if i didnt fill before.
I use allready `operator_save.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "operator_save_click");` and wait for postback . If I access the value on postback i get the old value

Comment: So probably you need `ViewState` or `Session` for this purpose.

Comment: ViewState and Session has no keys and values count is 0

Comment: Your question is a bit confuse. You want to send data to server without a postback, is that is?